# UDM Pro VPN with multiple clients on subnet to remote like subnet

Tags: networking, router, vpn, remote-desktop

Main subnet : 192.168.10.1/24 Remote subnet: 192.168.10.1/24 UDM Pro each location
I can only 12tp one client on the remote subnet, it refuses 2+ simultaneous connections.
I cannot site to site vpn, cannot get a static ip address
Any suggestions for how I can get multiple vpns from Site B to Site A?
Any ideas much appreciated

Tried to post on network engineering, but denied because the UDM Pro does not have manufacturer support